# Potential Skyrim (PC) Skeleton Key, Lock Picking Bug

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently started to play Skyrim again. I had played for about an hour or so and everything was fine. Then abruptly and without warning, the game application crashed\closed on me. I don't know exactly what caused it but I might suspect that it might have been Steam itself considering that when I was back on my desktop, Steam's Updater was up and waiting for user intervention.

I then went ahead and updated Steam. After it was done with the download and update install, I started Skyrim back up.

Now mind you, I've had over +99 lock picks on this file for over 2 or 3 years considering I still have and use the Skeleton Key. Every time I see any lock picks I grab them. However and just recently, I am seeing my lock picks decrease as they are now below 99. The last time I checked before saving the game and closing out the game application I had about 77 left.

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this as well, and if so, was there any solution you found to fix this bug? I should not be losing lock picks when possessing and using the Skeleton Key. Since I'm using the (PC) version, I have full access to the console.

Comment: Do you mean the amount of lockpicks in your inventory is decreasing, despite you not using them? And do you have a reason to assume the crash has anything to do with that possible bug?

Comment: @Joachim That's what I'm trying to figure out... I don't know if the crash has anything to do with it or not, the update to steam, etc... I don't know what is causing the bug. I have the Skeleton Key in inventory therefore when an attempt fails, it should not be breaking my lock picks. Yet, they are decreasing with each failed attempt.

Comment: Are you using mods?

Comment: The best way to determine what is happening is, now that you're below 99, break a lockpick and see if your count decreases? I wonder if the game attempts to use all lockpicks before using the skeleton key.

Comment: @Joachim No mods, pure vanilla, but I do have all official expansion packs.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf No, when I first got the Skeleton Key, my lockpicks value wouldn't change until I picked up more. I've been playing on this same file for about 3-4 years. This just started to happen.